# Javascript variable returning blank

Tags: javascript

I am testing this code:

```
var thecol = '';

// Note: I know that value.cat = '3'

if (value.cat === '1') {
        thecol = 'cat1';
    } else if (value.cat === '2') {
        thecol = 'cat2';
    } else if (value.cat === '3') {
        thecol = 'cat3';
    } else if (value.cat === '4') {
        thecol = 'cat4';
    } else if (value.cat === '5') {
        thecol = 'cat5';
    };

alert(thecol);
```

The alert is blank for some reason.

Any ideas why.

Comment: `value.cat` is clearly _not_ `'3'`. Use a debugger, your problem is in another castle. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/V8dWg/

Comment: Could it be that even though your value.cat === 3... it doesn't === '3'. I would suggest you change your equals to == instead. Triple equals means compare the type as well as the value... but if your value.cat is numeric, it wont match your tests as they are strings.

Comment: is it 3 or '3'? Also did you ever hear about a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)?

Comment: Why do you use === instade of ==? I think === means strictly the same object

Comment: for better result use switch cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that `value.cat` is `'3'` and not `3`? You can easily find out by logging `typeof value.cat`. Since you are using the deep equal it will only return true if both, the value and the type are the same:

```
'3' === 3 // -> false
'3' == 3 // -> true
```